# One reminder going out and one not

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I have a cron job set up and two reminders set to going out.

This one is going out fine when someone donates with the following settings
[image]

The second reminder for just a sign up is not sending. Any thoughts on why?
[image: i]

Comment: Try selecting the Actual date field too - If that didn't work then Try deleting the cron job and create a new job that might help

Comment: Try 1 hour after, just in case the 0 hour after a 'created date' isn't firing

Comment: tried 1 hr and actual date field still not working. will redo cron to see if that helps.